# How do i run two command lines in AWS simultaneously?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have a Django app that I am trying to deploy to AWS. 
I need two command lines to run the app. One command line will be used to runserver and another one to run a background task. That is how the app runs in my localserver.

How do I start two command lines in AWS?

Comment: linux server? check `nohup` or running as a service..

Comment: @DanielM Yes. Linux server. How do i use nohup? I want to start two commands: "python manage.py runserver" and "python manage.py process_tasks"

Comment: [DO NOT USE `runserver` on a publicly accessible AWS instance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#runserver). [Deploy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/) Django properly.

Comment: Need to +1 Alasdair's comment more than once. Runserver is *not* for deployment. (And you shouldn't need to run background tasks from the command line, either.)

Comment: Check running django with gunicorn+nginx - it is a better way.

Comment: @DanielRoseman We ran background tasks from command line with nohup. Is there any possible better option?

Comment: Yes, use Celery.

Answer (score 0):

As i can understand your django app is currently in development mode, I've used `tmux` for development mode, this [page](https://gist.github.com/MohamedAlaa/2961058) will guide you better to use tmux. Once you have started a tmux session run `python3 manage.py runserver` and then detach to the session using `ctrl-b` then press `d` and now your app will run even after you exit the shell.
To know more about tmux go through [this page](https://gist.github.com/MohamedAlaa/2961058).

In case you have to run your app in production mode Don't use above method, run your app  with any of `nginx` or `apache2` server. [This tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04) can guide you to set up your django app with nginx and gunicorn.

Answer (score 0):

[Supervisor](http://supervisord.org) is a good way to control that. You can run a lot of processes (like server, migration, collectstatic, Celery) easily.
Additionally, you can ensure that all processes will run again when your machine reboots.
And, as everybody said, you have to install a server in production that supports WSGI in order to run Django properly.